# Strange behavior with esri.tasks.locator

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm facing a very strange issue with respect to the `esri.tasks.locator` function. If I do a hard-refresh (Ctr+Shift+R), the map starts working without any error. But after that if just try to refresh again (normal F5), the console prints out

> TypeError: esri.tasks.Locator is not a constructor

Then if I again do a hard-refresh, everything works normally. What could be the cause of this behavior? The code I'm using is as follows:

```
dojo.require("esri.map");
dojo.require("esri.tasks.locator");
.
.
.

var locator = new esri.tasks.Locator("https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"); // this line is throwing error if not hard-refreshed
var params = {address:"200 E Berry St", maxLocations:1};
locator.addressToLocations(params);
locator.on("address-to-locations-complete", function (evt) { ... } );
```

Comment: you should be writing your code in AMD: https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/14/the-abcs-of-amd/

Answer (score 1):

Please use like this

```
require([
 "esri/tasks/locator"
], function (Locator) {
    var locator = new Locator("https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer"); // this line is throwing error if not hard-refreshed
    var params = {address:"200 E Berry St", maxLocations:1};
    locator.addressToLocations(params);
    locator.on("address-to-locations-complete", function (evt) { ... } );
});
```